# Display a Matrix field block entry when the block's entry exists

Tags: matrix

I have a `videoPost` block in a Matrix field. Each `videoPost` has a `imageField`. I am trying to display the block’s image if `imageField` is defined. This is returning images for each block that has `imageField` defined when I only want to return the specific block’s image.

```
{% for block in entry.matrixField.type('videoPost') %}
    {% if block.imageField | length %}
        {% for asset in block.imageField %}
            <img src="{{asset.getUrl}}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
{% for asset in block.imageField %}
    <img src="{{asset.getUrl}}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

with

```
{% set asset = block.imageField.first() %}
<img src="{{asset.getUrl}}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
```

If you're using Craft 3, replace .first() with .one()

Comment: This makes sense and I thought for sure this would solve it but this still returns images for each block.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an issue with your initial for loop? If I test your code as-is, the loop isn't limited to a single block, it's calling all of your videoPost blocks, so it's displaying all of the images associated with those blocks.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. Thank you. I removed the initial for loop and used the following `{% if block.imageField | length %}{% set asset = block.imageField.first() %}<img src="{{ siteUrl | trim('/') }}{{asset.getUrl}}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />{% endif %}`